# Catch Duplicate Pair in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Thanks in advance for everyone for helping me out, Please Help me out in Catching following pair of data.
Suppose I have a sheet that has two column, There are some rows which exactly match with other rows as shown in the image.
[Example of Duplicate Rows (pair of column)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX7CR.png)
In the Image Hi PRANAV, and HELLO BRINDA pair of column appear twice, I just want to hightlight them with red colour.
Please suggest me some Conditional formating code if possible.
Thanks

I tried highlighting duplicates but It worked for a column only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIFS. If it returns more than 1, then it's a duplicate:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2,$B$2:$B,$B2)>1
```

[image]